# how to use Conditional rendering with getX boolean observable

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

In my login controller:

```
class LoginController extends GetxController {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> loginFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  late TextEditingController emailController, passwordController;
  var isloading = false.obs;    <<<<<<<<<<<<
...
```

and in my view file:

```
 Container(
  color: Colors.blueGrey,
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 150,

  child: Obx(()=>
    Center(
      child: logincontroller.isloading ? CircularProgressIndicator(): Container(),

    ),
  )
)
```

however I keep getting this message:

> 33:50: Error: A value of type 'RxBool' can't be assigned to a variable
> of type 'bool'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `logincontroller.isLoading.value` to check the value of `RxBool`

Comment: thank you that solved that problem however:

now when the isloading variable changes to true (upon the login button click),

the circularprogressindicator doesnt show automatically. it only shows after i do a refresh/hot reload.

Comment: basically the widget didnt rebuild. when isloading changed value from false to true.
  child: Obx(()=>
                        Center(
                          child: logincontroller.isloading.value ? new CircularProgressIndicator(): new Container(child: Text('hello its false')),

                          


                        )

Comment: How do you change the value ?

Comment: using a login button to make a post call to the api. 

 Future<void> checkLogin() async {
    isloading = true.obs;  //right here.

Comment: Try changing the value like so  `isLoading.value = true`

Comment: you the real MVP. it worked!
can you explain to me why thats the case. 

Even tho the value technically was changing before as well?

Comment: Awesome, I'm glad I helped. This is how GetX works, try checking the in-depth documentation here https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx/blob/master/documentation/en_US/state_management.md